# Jenkins home page directs to getting started page

Tags: jenkins

We have a strange issue - our Jenkins main page (dashboard) has been disappeared and we see a "Getting Started" page instead of it.

The only thing we did was to clean logs in /var/log/jenkins.

Sorry for the lack of details, but we are literally ran out of theories.

Our question is what can be the possible cause of it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the reason was a buggy plugin -
Websocket Notifier it also flooded our jenkins logs (/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log) with such messages:

```
org.webbitserver.WebbitException: cannot send more responses than requests on
```

Once we deactivated this plugin and restarted jenkins - everything was back to normal.

Comment: Indeed, Websocket Notifier seems buggy. An issue is opened for this : https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62694